# How to display a datepicker on Symfony?

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I want to set up a date-picker for my date type fields based on symfony documentation. I have installed the package since packagist 'eternicode / bootstrap-datepicker'. I am able to apply my defined conditions for entering the date field in my js (like the date format) but the display is still impossible. I do not have an error message in my js console. I don't even see the datepikcer component..

My Form Type:

```
   ->add('date_entree', DateType::class, [ 
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                          'html5' => false,
                          'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
                ])

My JS:

    $(document).on('ready', function() {
         $('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
              format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
         });
     });
```

Have you please an idea about this issue?

Comment: I cannot tell you anything about potential JavaScript mistakes you may have made, but you for sure need to make sure that the Form component uses the same format as the datepicker when populating the form. For that, you will have to take a look at the [format option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format) of the `DateType`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
For DateType, I put    use \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType as DateType;

Comment: But you are still not using the `format` option (or you forgot to update the description after changing your code).

Comment: ->add('date_entree', DateType::class, [ 'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                          'html5' => false,
                          'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
                ]) https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format

Comment: This will not resolve my problem. I want to personalize my code from my js-datepicker class because it contains a lot of options. (for example, I want to set a start time in my calendar so the user can choose a date from this date)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

Finally, this was my solution:

- css:

  ```
   < link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  ```
- JS

  ```
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              // you may need to change this code if you are not using Bootstrap Datepicker
              $('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
                  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
              });
          });
      </script>
  ```
- Form Type

  ```
     ->add('date_entree', DateType::class, [ 
          'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
          ])
  ```

Hope that will be helpful for others developers!

Comment: For me not work. How is your twig file for this example?